# Unrecognized Selector: -[FBSDKLoginManager logInWithReadPermissions:fromViewController:handler:]:

Tags: ios, facebook, parse-platform

I just updated to Parse SDK 1.9.1 and FBSDK 4.7.1. I haven't changed any code, and all of a sudden when logging into Facebook I've been getting this error:

```
2015-10-30 13:49:01.392 [2834:809095] -[FBSDKLoginManager logInWithReadPermissions:fromViewController:handler:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x12de5d360
2015-10-30 13:49:01.404 [2834:809095] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FBSDKLoginManager logInWithReadPermissions:fromViewController:handler:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x12de5d360'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x182f60f48 0x197b13f80 0x182f67c5c 0x182f64c00 0x182e68cac 0x1003d254c 0x1003d136c 0x1003d11f0 0x100241758 0x100247578 0x100247de0 0x1002ec864 0x1002f08cc 0x1002f0618 0x1002ed504 0x1002f1c68 0x1002a1868 0x10012ec5c 0x10012edcc 0x1887a2f24 0x1887a2994 0x1887aaedc 0x1887b10c0 0x1887b04c4 0x18879af14 0x18879ab9c 0x18cd7f7c4 0x18cd7fb44 0x182f18544 0x182f17fd8 0x182f15cd8 0x182e44ca0 0x18e080088 0x18855cffc 0x10013071c 0x1983628b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

I'm not using `logInWithReadPermissions:fromViewController` as that wasn't available in the previous SDKs I had. I think Facebook just added that in, but it's not covered by the Parse SDKs. I'm using `class func logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions: [String]?, block: PFUserResultBlock?)`.

So it looks like I'm missing that viewController parameter but Parse says nothing about it. What should I do? Thanks!

Comment: Showing the code you're using to login to Facebook via Parse would be very useful, otherwise we can't actually see your problem.

Comment: I figured out why. I was calling `PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions()` inside the `FBSDKLoginButton` method, which generated two distinct callbacks.